# Get selected value from a loop generated drop-down-menu in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop, drop-down-menu

I would like to know what is the proper way to create several drop-down-menus (`<select>`), with a loop, where i can then **access** their selected value through a button.
I tried to recreate what I currently have in my code so i hope this is enough.

*(The reason i put `<select>` elements in an array is because i use different arrays to generate a table with rows in my original code.)*

Currently `getValue()`, that is trying to get the value from the 1st drop-down-menu, prints `''` which is the initial value, even when i change the value from the menu. I think the problem is  that putting them in array is causing them not to update their own value when changed. Is there a way to get around this problem?

This code is also causing `this.state.value` to only be set on the last drop-down-menu that was changed.
I understand why this is happening but i don't know how to get around it.

```
interface Props extends PanelProps<Options> {}

export class TablePanel extends Component<Props,{value: string, staterows:JSX.Element[]}> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleUniqueSelect = this.handleUniqueSelect.bind(this)
    this.state = {value: '', staterows:[] }
  }

  handleUniqueSelect(val:any){
     this.setState({value: val.currentTarget.value})    
  }

  populateRows(){
     let rows:any = []
     for(let index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
        rows.push(<select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleUniqueSelect }>
                        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
                        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                     </select>
                 );
     }
     this.setState({staterows: rows})    
  } 



 getValue(){
   if(this.state.staterows.length === 0)
    this.populateRows()
   console.log(this.state.staterows[0].props.value);
 }

 render(){
  
    return (
           <div>
            {this.state.staterows}     
             <button type='button' onClick={e=>this.getValue()} >Button</button>
           </div>   
          );
  }
}
```

I've added the example in [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-zhept?file=/index.js).
I changed `console.log(this.state.staterows[0].props.value);` to `console.log(this.state.staterows[0]);` because it had issues finding properties of unknown type.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in a small codesandbox example?

Comment: https://zhept.csb.app/  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-zhept?file=/index.js Here is the code from above. i changed `   console.log(this.state.staterows[0].props.value);` to `   console.log(this.state.staterows[0]); because it had issue with getting properties from unknow element. You should be able to see it in the console though.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-w5zfc?file=/index.js).

Note that you can return markup directly from a function without the need to store in state first, this is what I did with `populateRows`.

Value of each dropdown should be mapped to a specific index of an array in the state (or some other similar data structure to store multiple values). This maps a given dropdown's value to a specific item in an array: `value={this.state.values[index]}`

HTML elements in a `map` function in React must have unique `key` attribute so that React can correctly see what has changed between renders (there's actually more to that, but it's another topic). In my case I chose the index just for the example, but you can google about this and see how to correctly choose a unique key (rather use some known ID).

Initially the array in the state is empty so you get `[]` for the stringified value at the bottom. As you change values in dropdown the array will be filled/modified.

I hope this helps and of course, ask if there's something unclear.

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i was looking for!

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped!